# Error message "Unable to locate element"

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to identify a button which id defined under a class using XPATH, but it is throwing an error message "Unable to locate element".
**Details of class:**

```
<div class="aui-button-holder inputBtn" id="aui_3_4_0_1_202"> 
    <span class="aui-button aui-button-submit" id="aui_3_4_0_1_201"> 
    <span class="aui-button-content" id="aui_3_4_0_1_200">     
    <input class="aui-button-input aui-button-input-submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" id="aui_3_4_0_1_180">     
    </span>     
    </span>     
    <input type="button" class="aui-button-input aui-button-input-submit" onclick="parent.location='/web/offers/reg'" value="Register">         
</div>
```

**Code I have written:**

```
WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='aui_3_4_0_1_180']"));    
login.click();

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='aui_3_4_0_1_180']"}
```

Comment: With these things it's all about timing. Is this class dynamically added to the element? Or maybe that input is only available in DOM from some point? Instead of `XPATH` mind using `CSSSelectors` and check if that does work for you?

Comment: When it's a matter of timing switching from XPath to CSSSelectors will not solve your problem. In that case only waiting for the Element to be Clickable will help.

Comment: If my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The id does'nt belong to div, it is an id of an input.

You can use `//input[contains(@id,'aui_3_4_0_1_180')]` instead.

Comment: @Ratmir You might be right , i did not care about that id is dynamic or not. He can also use  **//input[contains(@value,'Sign In')]** . I think it is more simple than your solution :)

Comment: I agree with you if it is XPath, but I like more CSS selectors (readable and understandable in the future) :)

Yes, in some cases XPath is more powerful (you can do an action which cannot do with CSS selectors).

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the element to be clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='aui_3_4_0_1_180']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPath: `//div[@class="aui-button-holder inputBtn"]/*[@value="Sign In"]`.